# Numeric conversion error with PostgreSQL and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm getting the following error output when trying to run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` on an Ubuntu instance:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
```

And the following output as well:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:138:in `local_cache_key'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in `middleware'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:79:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/rails/gsc_surveying/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: I'm guessing its a version incompatibility issue. Rails 4.2 works with MRI Ruby 2.2 and possibly 2.3

Comment: Here's all of the output I'm getting: http://pastebin.com/jpwwZpr7

Comment: Can you please post the first line of the error message that tells the name and type of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to Ruby 2.3.1 fixed the issue.